# How can I find the distance between the offset and the line?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, canvas

I'm creating a function to draw and edit Lines using `CustomPaint()`.
It must be able to select the line to move or delete it.

To do this, I need to be able to detect if the offset where I touched is included in the line or if it is close to the line.

Use two offsets to draw a line as shown in the code below.
If so, how do I detect if the offset I touched is between these two offsets or if my offset is close to the line?

```
class Sketcher extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Shape> shapes;

  Sketcher(this.shapes) : super();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (var shape in shapes) {
      if (shape is Line) {
        canvas.drawLine(shape.p1!, shape.p2!, shape.paint);
      }
    }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: It does not look you have attempted anything yet... this is a basic geometry problem, maybe better suited for the math exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: the shortest distance between a point and a line segment is what you are looking for:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248617/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line passes through two points P1 = (x1, y1) and P2 = (x2, y2) then the distance of (x0, y0) from the line is:

[image]

---

#### so you can easily change this formula to dart

```
import 'dart:math';

main(){
  double x0 = -2;
  double x1 = 0;
  double x2 = 5/3;

  double y0 = 5;
  double y1 = 5/4;
  double y2 = 0;

  double numerator = (((x2 - x1)*(y1-y0)) - ((x1-x0)*(y2-y1))).abs();
  double denominator = sqrt(pow((x2-x1), 2) + pow((y2-y1), 2));

  double result = numerator / denominator;

  print(result);  /// 1.7999999999999998

}
```

source of Math:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line